# React: How to force a function to run after another one is totally completed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this React Pomodoro Clock, there is a function `countDown`. In it there is a function called `three`. Currently, when `this.setState({ init: 'break' });`  is set in `two`, `three` occurs immediately. However, `three` should wait until `two` completes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

/*
* A simple React component
*/
const initState = {
  breakLength: 5,
  breakSeconds: undefined,
  sessionLength: 25,
  sessionSeconds: undefined,
  init: 'session',
  timeLeft: undefined,
  timeLeftSeconds: undefined,
  started: false,
  intervalFunc: undefined
}

const secondsToMins = (time) => {
  //let converted = Math.floor(time / 60) + ':' + ('0' + Math.floor(time % 60)).slice(-2);
  let converted = ('0' + Math.floor(time / 60)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + Math.floor(time % 60)).slice(-2);

  //console.log('converted')
  //console.log(converted)
  //console.log('#######')

  return converted;
}

class Clock extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initState;
    this.breakDecrement = this.breakDecrement.bind(this);
    this.breakIncrement = this.breakIncrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionDecrement = this.sessionDecrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionIncrement = this.sessionIncrement.bind(this);
    this.startStop = this.startStop.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // seconds are used for the countDown()
    // seconds are converted to MM:SS at every t-minus
    let breakSeconds = this.state.breakLength * 60;
    let sessionSeconds = this.state.sessionLength * 60;

    // Initialize everything
    this.setState({ breakSeconds: breakSeconds });
    this.setState({ sessionSeconds: sessionSeconds });
    this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: sessionSeconds });
    this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(sessionSeconds) });

  }

  breakDecrement() {
    // decrements the breakLength and the breakSeconds
    // breakLength is only a number ie. 5 (does not show seconds)
    // breakSeconds is that nunber converted into seconds
    let breakLength = this.state.breakLength - 1;
    if (breakLength > 0 && breakLength < 61){
      this.setState({ breakLength: breakLength });
      let breakSeconds = breakLength * 60;
      this.setState({ breakSeconds: breakSeconds });
    }
  }

  breakIncrement() {
    // same as decrement except does increment
    let breakLength = this.state.breakLength + 1;
    if (breakLength > 0 && breakLength < 61){
      this.setState({ breakLength: breakLength });
      let breakSeconds = breakLength * 60;
      this.setState({ breakSeconds: breakSeconds });
    }
  }

  sessionDecrement() {
    // decrements the sessionLength and the sessionSeconds
    // sessionLength is only a number ie. 25 (does not show seconds)
    // sessionSeconds is that nunber converted into seconds
    let sessionLength = this.state.sessionLength - 1;
    if (sessionLength > 0 && sessionLength < 61){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength-1,
        sessionSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength-1)*60,
        timeLeftSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength-1)*60,
        timeLeft:  secondsToMins((prevState.sessionLength-1)*60)})
      );
    }
  }

  sessionIncrement() {
    // same as decrement except does increment
    let sessionLength = this.state.sessionLength + 1;
    if (sessionLength > 0 && sessionLength < 61){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength+1,
        sessionSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength+1)*60,
        timeLeftSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength+1)*60,
        timeLeft:  secondsToMins((prevState.sessionLength+1)*60)})
      );
    }
  }

  startStop(id) {
    // starts the countDown, which runs continuously until the start/stop button
    // is pressed again, which pauses the countdown.
    // the id parameter is used by countDown to play the audio beep
    if(!this.state.started){
      this.countDown(id);
      this.setState({ started: true});
    }
    // pauses the countDown
    if(this.state.started){
      let intervalFunc = this.state.intervalFunc;
      clearInterval(intervalFunc);
      this.setState({ started: false});
    }
  }

  reset() {
    let intervalFunc = this.state.intervalFunc;
    clearInterval(intervalFunc);
    // reset state to default values
    this.setState({ breakLength: 5 });
    this.setState({ sessionLength: 25 });
    this.setState({ init: 'session' });
    this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: 1500})
    this.setState({ timeLeft: '25:00' });
  }

  countDown(id){
    // set the function to a variable and set state to it, so the function
    // can be paused with clearInterval()
    var intervalFunc = setInterval(() => down(this.state.timeLeftSeconds--), 1000);
    this.setState({intervalFunc: intervalFunc});

    const down = (time) =>
    {

      const one = async () =>{
        if(time > 0){
          // converts seconds to MM:SS at every t-minus
          this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time)});
          console.log(time);
          console.log(this.state.timeLeft);
        }
        return;
      }

      //when time reaches 0 set state.init to break
      // and set seconds left to break seconds
      const two = async () => {
        if(time == 0 && this.state.init == 'session'){
          this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time)});
          let sound = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0];
          this.setState({ init: 'break' });
          console.log(this.state.init)
          sound.play();
          this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: this.state.breakSeconds});
        }
        return;
      }

      //when time reaches 0 set state.init to session
      // and set seconds left to session seconds
      const three = async () => {
        if(time == 0 && this.state.init == 'break'){
          this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time)});
          let sound = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0];
          this.setState({ init: 'session' });
          console.log(this.state.init)
          sound.play();
          this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: this.state.sessionSeconds});
        }
        return;
      }

      one().then(two).then(three);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="clock">
      <h1 id="title">25-5 Clock</h1>

      <div>
      <p id="break-label">Break Length</p>
      <p id="break-length">{this.state.breakLength}</p>
      <button id="break-decrement" onClick={e => this.breakDecrement()}> Decrease </button>
      <button id="break-increment" onClick={e => this.breakIncrement()}> Increase </button>
      </div>

      <div>
      <p id="session-label">Session Length</p>
      <p id="session-length">{this.state.sessionLength}</p>
      <button id="session-decrement" onClick={e => this.sessionDecrement()}> Decrease </button>
      <button id="session-increment" onClick={e => this.sessionIncrement()}> Increase </button>
      </div>

      <hr/>

      <div>
      <p id="timer-label">{this.state.init}</p>
      <p id="time-left">{this.state.timeLeft}</p>
      <button id="start_stop" onClick={e => this.startStop(e.target.id)}><audio id="beep" src='./beep.mp3'></audio> start/stop </button>
      <button id="reset" onClick={e => this.reset()}> reset </button>
      </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
};

/*
* Render the above component into the div#app
*/
ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>25-5 Clock</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div id="app"></app>
    </main>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Edited with @Jason code.

Comment: The error is possibly because the down function attempts to update state and then use state.secondsTimeRemaining with the updated value. It may be that the down function can only use the time value that was passed to it when the time function was initialized. This is not related to the completion order of the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Use an array to hold states and duration:

```
const states = [ { name: 'session', duration: 1500 }, { name: 'break', duration: 300 } ]
```

Alternate the index of the array to alternate between session and break.

```
countDown(id){
    // set the function to a variable and set state to it, so the function
    // can be paused with clearInterval()
    var intervalFunc = setInterval(() => down(this.state.timeLeftSeconds--), 1000);
    this.setState({intervalFunc: intervalFunc});

    const down = (time) =>
    {

      if(time > 0){
        // converts seconds to MM:SS at every t-minus
        this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time)});
        console.log(time);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeft);
      }

      if (time <= 0) {
        this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time)});
        let sound = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0];
        sound.play();

        let stateIndex = (this.state.stateIndex + 1) % states.length;
        this.setState({ stateIndex: stateIndex});
        this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: states[stateIndex].duration});
        this.setState({ init: states[stateIndex].name});
        console.log(this.state.init);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make them asynchronous.

like...

```
const one = async () => {
  //some code
return
}
const two = async () => {
  //some code
return
}
const three = async () => {
  //some code
return
}
```

Then you can...

```
one().then(two).then(three)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by making the functions return a `Promise` and using the `async / await` keywords to wait until they're finished before starting the next.

```js
const setDelay = delay => new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log(`Process running for ${delay}`);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Process done');
    resolve();
  }, delay);
});

(async () => {
  
  await setDelay(2000);
  await setDelay(3000);
  await setDelay(1000);
  
})();
```

Or you could do without `async / await` and chain the promises.

```js
const setDelay = delay => new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log(`Process running for ${delay}`);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Process done');
    resolve();
  }, delay);
});

setDelay(3000)
  .then(() => setDelay(1000))
  .then(() => setDelay(4000));
```

Or just use good 'ol fashioned callbacks. But I'd go with one of the above.